# bash script starting new shell and continuing to run commands

Tags: bash, shell, jupyter-notebook, pipenv

I'm a complete noob to writing bash scripts. I'm trying to do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir New_Project
cd New_Project
pipenv install ipykernel
pipenv shell
python -m ipykernel install --user --name==new-virtual-env
jupyter notebook
```

The problem I'm having is that after it executes `pipenv shell`, it starts the new shell and then doesn't execute the last two commands. When I exit the new shell it then tries to execute the remaining lines. Is there any way to get a script to run all of these commands from start to finish?

Comment: You could enter the venv with `source $(pipenv --venv)/bin/activate`. That would activate the virtual environment that you created with `pipenv install` without opening a new shell (which is what `pipenv shell` does). Then you need to use `deactivate` (not `exit`) to stop the venv. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per the [manual](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pipenv#other-commands) :

> shell will spawn a shell with the virtualenv activated.

which is not what you need. Instead use `run` :

> run will run a given command from the virtualenv, with any arguments
>   forwarded (e.g. $ pipenv run python).

In your case, something like

```
pipenv run python -m ipykernel install --user --name==new-virtual-env
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! just to clarify `pipenv run` will run any shell command i.e. `pipenv run scrapy` etc. not just python