# Is it possible to use pipenv in same shell (not subshell)?

Tags: python-3.x, pipenv

I'm new to pipenv. I'm used to virtualenv, where I can source a script to "activate" the env in my current shell. Is there a way to use pipenv that way, rather than starting a subshell? I.e. `source $(pipenv shell-env)` or something like that? I'd like to have a linear shell history, not have to double-exit to exit the terminal window, etc.
I'm using python 3.6 and 3.7 on Mac and Windows primarily.

Comment: I suppose one could write a script to invoke the subshell, write the env out to a tmp file, and diff the two environments to produce a "source"able set of shell commands. Has anyone tried that?

Comment: I have this exact same issue.  Pipenv is a PITA with this. Needlessly creating a subshell that wreaks all kind of havoc with tmux `wait-for`s etc. Did you ever get around this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bash script starting new shell and continuing to run commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48056606/bash-script-starting-new-shell-and-continuing-to-run-commands)

Comment: Nope -- the accepted answer is correct. You need to `source` the activate script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Linux or macOS:

```
source "$(pipenv --venv)/bin/activate"
```

On Windows (using bash; thanks @Nickolay):

```
source "$(pipenv --venv)/Scripts/activate"
```

Comment: Or `source "$(pipenv --venv)/Scripts/activate"` on Windows (using MINGW and bash).