# Making shell script which does someting after pipenv shell

Tags: python, pipenv

I want to make shell which does a few things in a row like.

```
pipenv shell
export PYTHONPATH="/MyFunction/:$PYTHONPATH"
python manage.py runserver 8001
```

However `pipenv shell` once works, `export` and `python manage.py` doesn't work on `pipenv shell`

Is there any good way to set one-stop script?

Comment: `pipenv shell` starts a new shell, blocking the rest of your script until that shell exits. Do you want the `export` to happen in *that* shell, or in your current shell once `pipenv shell` completes?

Comment: I suspect you want something like `pipenv run manage.py runserver 8001`, with whatever you have in `/MyFunction` being installed in the virtual environment managed by `pipenv`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bash script starting new shell and continuing to run commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48056606/bash-script-starting-new-shell-and-continuing-to-run-commands)